# No class def found for SOAPConnectionFactory

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am re-building an application from Java 8 in Java 9 (jdk 9.0.4), using modules. One of these modules requires making SOAP calls to our server to check if various services are running, and then reports back the status of those services via email.

I understand that the SOAP libraries have been deprecated in Java 9 but not removed yet. I have the `java.xml.ws` module declared as a requirement in the appropriate module-info:

```
module services {
    exports com.nams.hyperion.services;

    requires configurations;
    requires java.xml.ws;
}
```

It compiles, but I get an error when I try running the project: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/soap/SOAPConnectionFactory`

```
scf = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance(); <-- error here
conn = scf.createConnection();
mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
msg = mf.createMessage();
```

I tried using the `--add-modules java.xml.ws` compiler option, but that doesn't resolve the problem; does my Java installation not have this module? What are my options? I've mucked around maven a bit looking for a separate distribution but haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Maven distribution that I could use: https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/rt-jdk9/2.3.0/jar

However, the module-info file gives me a warning that my module reads `java.xml.ws` from 2 identically named sources; but the project runs, which is all that matters to me at the moment. I'll work out how to deal with the ambiguity later and update this answer if I manage to do it.

Update:
I solved the ambiguity by removing the jar file from the module's dependencies, but retaining it in Maven's dependencies list.